# Regex - how do i match the first part of an indexed path

Tags: c#, regex

for the line

```
Tester[0]/Test[4]/testId
Tester[0]/Test[4]/testId
Test[1]/Test[4]/testId
Test[2]/Test[4]/testId
```

I want to match the first part of the path including the first [, n and ] and first /
so for line above I would get

```
Tester[0]
Tester[0]
Test[1]
Test[2]
```

I have tried using

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^\[.*\]\/");
var res = rx.Replace("Tester[0]/Test[4]/testId", "", 1 /*only one occurrence */);
```

i get

```
res == "testId";
```

rather than

```
res == "Test[4]/testId"
```

which is what im hoping for
so its matching the first open square bracket and the last closing bracket.
I need it to match only the first closing bracket

**Update:**
Sorry, i am trying to match the first forward slash also.

```
Tester[0]/
Tester[0]/
Test[1]/
Test[2]/
```

**Solution:**
to remove the first match using "?":

```
var rx = new Regex(@"^.*?\[.*?\]\/");
var res = rx.Replace("Tester[0]/Test[4]/testId", "", 1 /*only one occurrence */);
```

Comment: I'm confused... you're trying to remove the first part of the path, right? As in everything up to and including the first slash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this was your original regex pattern: `^.*\[.*\]/` (the pattern in your question does not match the lines).

This pattern uses *greedy* quantifiers (`*`), so, even though we only requested one match, the pattern itself matches more than we'd like. As you noticed, it matched until the second occurrence of the square brackets.

We can make this pattern *non-greedy* by adding question marks to the quantifiers: `^.*?\[.*?\]/`.

Although this works for your use-case, a better pattern may be: `^[^/]+/`. This removes any character up to the first forward-slash. The `[^ ... ]` is a negative character class (the brackets are unrelated to the brackets in the strings we're matching against). In this case, it matches any character that *isn't* a forward-slash.

For this simple text manipulation, though, we could just use a `String.Substring()` instead of regular expressions:

```
line.Substring(line.IndexOf('/') + 1);
```

This is faster and easier to understand than a regular expression pattern.

Comment: Haha, this was my first solution. But i want to keep one that have no [n] in the string. Thats why im here. But im still a regex nuoob

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Is this not the result you're looking for: `res == "Test[4]/testId"`?

Comment: no. I want to match Test[4]/ so i can trim it from the origonal

Comment: I need the first alpha word followed by an open bracket, a number and a close bracket. But my matches match too much. That case would work. but its too simple. 
I need the first Test[0]/ of Test[0]/TestSomthinElse[8]/TestID

Comment: Oh, I see. I think you were doing it backwards--you wanted to match the first part and then remove it from the actual path in two steps, right?

Answer (score 0):

Is this the sort of thing you are looking for?

**updated**

```
var str="Tester[0]/Test[4]/testId\nTester[0]/Test[4]/testId\nTest[1]/Test[4]/testId\nTest[2]/Test[4]/testId"

console.log(str)
//  Tester[0]/Test[4]/testId
//  Tester[0]/Test[4]/testId
//  Test[1]/Test[4]/testId
//  Test[2]/Test[4]/testId

var str2=str.replace(/\/.+/mg,"")

console.log(str2)
//  Tester[0]
//  Tester[0]
//  Test[1]
//  Test[2]
```

this works by starting the match at the first '/'  and then ending when the line ends and replaces this match with " ". the m flags multi-line and the g flags to do a global match.

Comment: I will give it a go.

Comment: Ok. i know thats the java script regex engine but it matches the whole string when i try it on my set.

Comment: OK i see thats going on. Im trying to REMOVE the match, not keep it.

Comment: I can get that to work but its dirty. I can use the expression to get the match then replace the start of the string with the length of the match but that feels dirty.

Comment: but you are on the right track. is there a way to replace all be the first match?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lookahead` and `lookbehind` approach to find matching and replace accordingly :

With `lookaround` approach, your regex would be like this :

```
(?=/).*(?<=])
```

Comment: relevant example?

Comment: @Justin I didn't get you. I've tested it with your test cases and it's working as expected.

Comment: I have a solution but yours most likely works also. Using the non-greedy operator "?"

Comment: I had assumed your output to be `"Test[4]/testId"` for input `Tester[0]/Test[4]/testId`

Comment: Above regex matches with first forward slash(/) untill last occurence of closing square bracket(]). Lookaround is zero width assertion as you can see they do not include matching character(forward slash and closing square bracket)

Comment: In the solution i chose i am replacing the first match with the "" so it works fine.

Comment: That's perfect. In your solution, you can check numbers in the indexer by using `^.*?\[\d+]\/`. Along with that, with my solution using `.*?(?<=/)`, you can replace that matching.